Why does the solve() function of OrdinaryDiffEq cause a memory leak in older versions of Julia?
I ran into a seemingly common issue while using the solve function of OrdinaryDiffEq, where the function would allocate memory that was not vacated. For context, I observed this memory leak while using Julia 1.9 and the most recent edition of OrdinaryDiffEq. When I updated Julia to 1.10, the memory leak disappeared.
This question is to open a thread to understand why this occurred. I suspect that it has to do with the changes to garbage collection in Julia 1.10. For those who are unaware, the 1.10 version introduced parallelized garbage collection to increase speeds, and I think that this changed introduced a memory leak in older versions of OrdinaryDiffEq.
I suspect this is the case because the solution as stated in the following threads...
https://github.com/SciML/DifferentialEquations.jl/issues/680
https://github.com/SciML/OrdinaryDiffEq.jl/issues/1946
https://github.com/SciML/DifferentialEquations.jl/issues/1001
https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/49761
...is to manually call the garbage collector after you calculate the solution. I can confirm that this is a valid band-aid fix, but it increases the time to do multiple integrations by a significant factor. So, if you're following any of the aforementioned threads, an update should fix the issue.
